# How to fit a long tag in a text area with CSS?

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I break the tag so that it can fit in that white area? 
Here all CSS codes I've tried so far.

```
`.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-match-item {
    background-color: #596272 !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: initial;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 7px 12px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    /* padding-right: 10px !important; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
    /* min-width: 500px; */
    /* word-break: break-word; */
    line-break: after-white-space;
    /* position: relative; */
}`
```

[Problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X1XE.png)

Comment: Please share a working example using stack snippet

Comment: @yavselyil Can you please sent HTML code as well so we can solve your problem.

Comment: Did you try `word-wrap: break-word;` ?

Comment: have you tried to use white-space property? like white-space:pre; or normal